# How to filter json data in java script while selecting check box in drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

rails 4 + Javascript + jquery

I have a drop down filter with multiple select check box(autocomplete check box). i want to implement a client side filter on javascript  by origin_name.

In drop down a list will come like "ABC,XYZ,PQR....". While selecting one origin_name data should come in a table with particular_id....

Any suggestion how to implement ?

json data is coming like this

```
 @bus_schedules =  [{"id":470,"origin_name":ABC},
    {"id":446,"origin_name":XYZ},
    {"id":465,"origin_name":PQR},
    {"id":442,"origin_name":LUV}
    ]        
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var json_data = <%= raw @bus_schedules.to_json %>
    //TODO Code
    </script>



<table class="table table-hover table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Travels</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
         <% if @bus_schedules.blank? %>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="7">
              <center>
               <div class='alert alert-danger' style="width:100%;">
                   Opps! No Record Found!
               </div>
               </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
         <% else %>
            <% @bus_schedules.each do |bus_schedule| %>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <b>
                      <span id="res_service_name_218484"><%= @get_operators_hash[bus_schedule.operator_id] %></span>
                    </b>               
                 </td>
              </tr>
         <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: var json_data = <%=@json_data.to_json.html_safe %>

Comment: Data is coming fine Bharat.but you know how to do this any hint/idea ?

Comment: Yes, because when we use any jquery plugin that always take data into json format so in ruby the to_json will generate json data and html_safe is just a method to actually "sets the string" as HTML Safe

Comment: Ok Bharat can you give me hint or Idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: which problem can you please elaborate more in detail ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you wants to implement.

Comment: Your are creating several `<span>` with the same `id=res_service_name_218484' which is wrong. You cannot have more than one element with the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want.

This converts the json data into an html select.

[**see jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7KKkw/)

```
var json_array = [
    {"id":470, "origin_name":"ABC"},
    {"id":446, "origin_name":"XYZ"},
    {"id":465, "origin_name":"PQR"},
    {"id":442, "origin_name":"LUV"}
], html = '<select>';

// map the json data into an html select 
$.map(json_array, function(json) {
  html += '<option value="' + json.id + '">'
           + json.origin_name + '</option>';
});
html += '</select>';

$("body").append(
    $(html).change(function () {
        alert('you selected ' + ($(this).val()));
    })
);
```

---

EDIT:

This new version only shows the table rows that match the filter criteria. Not exactly your table structure, but you get the hang of it.

[**updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7KKkw/1/)

---

EDIT2:

Now using check boxes filter: [**jsFiddle3**](http://jsfiddle.net/7KKkw/3/)

Comment: Jose i am showing whole data in a table (<tr><td>) ok .first time it will hit the server and it will get the full data ok now i will save full data in json format in js variable ok then i need to use this json data only in filters because i dont want that everytime it will hit the server ok

Comment: Can you post a sample of your table? I need to know the table markup in order to do the filtering.

Comment: and Jose this approach will work but how can i replace the particular table data.

Comment: Yes Jose please check it i posted.

Comment: Yes Jose its a good approach thanks! i think i will make it ready but one thing i am using check boxes in drop down. i mean user can select multiple things Right!

Comment: Jose I am trying to merge both <select> with check box not getting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45458/discussion-between-rajesh-gurbani-and-jose-rui-santos)